# Xamarin AWS GetMedia return unknown error

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-kinesis

I am developing a Xamarin video consumer application in Xamarin and I am getting the following error:

Amazon.KinesisVideoMedia.AmazonKinesisVideoMediaException: The service returned an error. See inner exception for details. ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.

The error code in the exception is null. I included a snapshot of my screen with the detailed error.

code:

```cs
async Task TaskeGetMedia()
{
    var cancelToken = new CancellationToken();
    var config = new  AmazonKinesisVideoMediaConfig();
    Console.WriteLine(config.ToString());
    AmazonKinesisVideoMediaClient client = new AmazonKinesisVideoMediaClient("AKIAI33DOGUTJP4VOOBQ", "ZLMkUv/j6PGJCtqxIJW4/d4tI24AFA1iV0l22Wn5", "https://541221181757.signin.aws.amazon.com/console");
    GetMediaRequest Myrequest = new GetMediaRequest();
    Myrequest.StreamARN = "arn:aws:kinesisvideo:us-west-2:541321181757:stream/demo/1528677884275";
    Myrequest.StreamName = "demo";
    Myrequest.StartSelector = new StartSelector();
    Myrequest.StartSelector.StartSelectorType = StartSelectorType.EARLIEST;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = await client.GetMediaAsync(Myrequest, cancelToken);
            Console.WriteLine(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something is thrown ! " + ex.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should not have a while(true) in your code.. And an AmazonKinesisVideoMediaClient can call the GetMedia method maximum 5 times per second!

Comment: If I take out the while loop the result is the same. Same error in the first interaction.